# Problem with GRUB resolution - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, display-resolution, grub-efi

I have been using Ubuntu for quite sometime now. I have a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. I have used this combo ever since Ubuntu 18.04 came out. Earlier, grub would always show and accept 1920x1080 as its display resolution. I have had various system crashes along the way due to which I have had to install Windows and Ubuntu thrice. Recently, I have noticed a peculiar thing. My grub doesn't show 1920x1080 resolution when I use videoinfo command at grub terminal. The highest that it goes is 1280x720. I have tried to fix it by manually making an entry in the grub file but it was of no help.

[image: My grub file config is as follows:]

Can anyone please suggest me a possible fix for it? Is there something wrong with the OS? Is there something wrong with the BIOS (MSI Motherboard)? Is there something wrong with the drivers?

Note: I am running in UEFI mode.

Comment: Use `locate vudeoindo` and then `ll` followed by one space and copy and pasted result from the locate command. What is the date and time for the module? Mine is January 2019 and 1929x1080 still works fine.

Comment: When you are in grub, press c, and at command prompt `grub>` type `videoinfo`. What is grub's output? Do you get something similar to what I had described in section "Update 1" of my [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133622/overcoming-black-text-and-blank-screens-between-plymouth-and-gdm-login-boot-stag)?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and find the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Then change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"
```

See that this will sort out your problem. Also note the advice at the beginning of the file:

> If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

Answer (score 0):

There's very little video control at the GRUB screen level. It's best to leave `/etc/default/grub` at...

`GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`

This parameter only effects the GRUB screen, and this setting will display large enough font characters for easy viewing.

Followed by...

`sudo update-grub`

Also see...

[How to fix plymouth (splash screen) in all Ubuntu releases!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases)

[Nvidia Grub max boot resolution 1280x1024 (15.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741772/nvidia-grub-max-boot-resolution-1280x1024-15-10?rq=1)

[Grub-Efi wrong resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224665/grub-efi-wrong-resolution?rq=1)

Comment: I used to do it that way too but you can really do a lot with grub video. I'll try to post something later.

Comment: No, I want to know why am I unable to set my grub resolution beyond 720p now when earlier I could do it with a breeze. What could be the solution to the problem? The main thing is that I am trying to fix my slpash screen after my nvidia driver installation but it is quite low res. And I pretty sure that as various solutions have stated, if I can change the resolution of the grub, the resolution of the splash screen would too.

Comment: @c2yCharlie I don't know if display managers even come into play this early, but could it be the difference between lightdm and gdm3? Maybe even the nvidia drivers?

Comment: @c2yCharlie I'd worry more about "I have had various system crashes along the way due to which I have had to install Windows and Ubuntu thrice". Do you know why this occurred?

Comment: Yes, I know. Most of them were due to my foolishness. Nothing that happened all by itself or due to some system fault. However, I cannot think of a single reason why grub would stop displaying 1920x1080 in videoinfo as it used to previously. No matter how many grub changes I make, it just doesn't accept this resolution and always reverts back to 1280x720. I had installed proprietary drivers for Nvidia which caused my splash (plymouth) to revert to a low resolution. Prior to the driver installation, the splash screen was running on my native resolution. The whole matter is pretty strange.

Comment: @c2yCharlie see https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases and https://askubuntu.com/questions/741772/nvidia-grub-max-boot-resolution-1280x1024-15-10?rq=1 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/224665/grub-efi-wrong-resolution?rq=1

Comment: @heynnema I am really thankful to you for your help and support but sadly, it did not work. Nothing actually worked. I moved from Ubuntu to Fedora for this very reason and it's also giving the same problem. Just so tired of it.